# Telerik RadControls setup issue

Tags: telerik

I just ran the Telerik update wizard for Teleriks RadControls for ASP.NET because for some reason my web.config was not setup to run RadControls. It modified my web.config. I am not getting the following error:

*ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.*

If i revert my web.config back to the backup i get this error:

*'~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: '~/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd' is missing in web.config. RadScriptManager requires a HttpHandler registration in web.config. Please, use the control Smart Tag to add the handler automatically, or see the help for more information: Controls > RadScriptManager*

If i refrain from using the RadScriptManager and revert back to using a normal ScriptManager, my project works fine. Except on some pages when i operation is performed i receive the following error:

*Sys.InvalidOperationException: A control is already associated with the element.*

The above error was why i attempted to us the RadScriptManager in the first place...

Has anyone run into this issue before and perhaps know what is going on?
D

Comment: If you could paste in your web.config code, minus any confidential info, I could take a look at it, I don't think the problems that bad based on what you have said.

Answer (score 1):

the handler is not registered correctly. Click on the smart tag of the RadScriptManager and choose "register"

or copy the settings from this web.config file (.net45)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
        <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>

            <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />

        </httpModules>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="RadCompression" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />

        </modules>
        <handlers>

            <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
            <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
            <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```